# Multiple radio button array for php form

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, radio-button

I'm new to this. I'm studying web development and have to create a php response form for a questionnaire which then inputs into a database. I'm having trouble with the radio buttons. I can't create the right code that makes an array and displays the answers in the response form/page.

This is my code:

```
<form name="modulequestionnaire" method="post" action="tania.responseform.php" />

<p><i>Rate each question from 6 to 1, six being strongly 
agree and one being strongly disagree.</i></p>

1. I think the module guide/student handbook provided enough information about the 
module content, organisation and assessment.<br/>

6<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="6"> 5<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="5"> 
4<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="4"> 3<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="3"> 
2<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="2"> 1<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="1">
</p>

2.The module was well organised.<br/>

6<input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="6"> 5<input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="5"> 
4<input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="4"> 3<input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="3"> 
2<input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="2"> 1<input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="1"> 
</p>

3.The Learning Resource Centre provided adequate materials for the module.<br/>

6<input type="radio" name="answer[3]" value="6"> 5<input type="radio" name="answer[3]" value="5"> 
4<input type="radio" name="answer[3]" value="4"> 3<input type="radio" name="answer[3]" value="3"> 
2<input type="radio" name="answer[3]" value="2"> 1<input type="radio" name="answer[3]" value="1"> 
</p>
```

I know the answer can relate to the isset function but I don't know how to code it.
Could someone possibly teach or help me out here?

Comment: Can you post your existing PHP attempt?

Comment: @HC_ I want to create answers for the questions above.

Comment: @sjagr something like this but it doesnt work.:     <?php

$answer=$_POST['answer'];

print "Answers: ";
switch ($answer) {
 case 1:
  print "6<br/>";
  break;
 case 2:
  print "5<br/>";
  break;
 case 3:
  print "4<br/>";
  break;
 case 4;
  print "3<br/>";
  break;
 case 5;
  print "2<br/>";
  break;
 case 6;
  print "1<br/>";
  break;};
  


?>

Comment: Please post your attempts in your question instead of in comment. It's easier for people to read also. @taniakeira

Comment: @Fred-ii- okay I will, sorry, new to this.

Comment: No problemo @taniakeira Welcome to StackOverflow. Take the tour => http://stackoverflow.com/tour if you have any questions that may not be answered sometimes. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're unsure of how to handle the HTML markup that you've set up, you should `var_dump($_POST)` the values that are sent to the PHP handler page so you know what the format will look like, that way you can proceed from there.

When I created your HTML and tested it with a `var_dump` and some random selections, the output was

```
array(2) { ["answer"]=> array(3) { [1]=> string(1) "5" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "4" } ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }
```

Notice that there is an array within the `$_POST['answer']` variable. So you should `foreach` over each element in that array to handle each respective value:

```
foreach ($_POST['answer'] as $answer) {
    // do stuff with the answer
}
```

If you need to work with the answer number that you defined in the `POST` array, you can `foreach` with a key:

```
foreach ($_POST['answer'] as $answerNum => $answer) {
    // do stuff with $answerNum and $answer
}
```

You can, of course, access your answer by its number directly:

```
if (!empty($_POST['answer'][1])) { // To ensure that the value is being sent
    // do stuff with $_POST['answer'][1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't imagine that this is quite what you are looking to do. If instead you give the three questions different names:

```
<form name="modulequestionnaire" method="post" action="tania.responseform.php" />

<p><i>Rate each question from 6 to 1, six being strongly 
agree and one being strongly disagree.</i></p>

1. I think the module guide/student handbook provided enough information about the 
module content, organisation and assessment.<br/>

6<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="6"> 5<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="5"> 
4<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="4"> 3<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="3"> 
2<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="2"> 1<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="1">
</p>

2.The module was well organised.<br/>

6<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="6"> 5<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="5">



4<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="4"> 3<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="3"> 
2<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="2"> 1<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="1"> 
</p>

3.The Learning Resource Centre provided adequate materials for the module.<br/>

6<input type="radio" name="answer3" value="6"> 5<input type="radio" name="answer3" value="5"> 
4<input type="radio" name="answer3" value="4"> 3<input type="radio" name="answer3" value="3"> 
2<input type="radio" name="answer3" value="2"> 1<input type="radio" name="answer3" value="1"> 
</p>
```

then in php all you will need to do is find the values using the `$_POST` variable as such

```
<?php 
    echo $_POST['answer1'];
    echo $_POST['answer2'];
    echo $_POST['answer3'];
?>
```

Comment: This works but derives from the purpose of the lesson that OP needs to learn about creating and handling `POST` arrays. It is especially useful to code using `POST` arrays because it means less work to add in a single question if the code is done right.

Comment: True, I guess I would personally stay away from post arrays because they can become confusing quickly. I only really use post arrays when I have a varying number of inputs that I am taking in, such as a multiselect, I am not sure why you would want to use an array in this case though. Except for the sake of a lesson... okay, you win this round :)