# How to store the values of all radio buttons checked by the user in a page in PHP on submit

Tags: php, post, radio-button

I have the following PHP code displaying the set of questions and multiple answers in a radio buttons.

```
foreach ($cursor as $obj)
{
    echo ' '.$result["question"].'<br><br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="cl[]"> '.$result["ch1"].'<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="cl[]"> '.$result["ch2"].'<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="cl[]"> '.$result["ch3"].'</p>';
}

<button type="submit"  >Submit</button>
```

I tried following code which is not working,

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  foreach($_POST['cl'] as $selected) {
    echo "<p>".$selected ."</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

How to store these multiple values in an array?
 How to navigate these array values into another page named page1 on submit?
 How to access these values in another page named page1?

The format would look like below

```
Part of main memory where it stores data temporarirly

     ROM
     FLOPPY DISK
     RAM

It is a component of operating system that exposes function to user and applications

     Shell
     Kernel
     Shell and Kernel
```

Comment: try to for() nor foreach()

Comment: Well, your input fields doesn't have a value? So I'm not sure if that's why you're not seeing anything.

Comment: If you want to select multiple options then you should use checkbox.

Comment: @Ravi I will have to rephrase the question its not multiple values for a button. I have user selected multiple radio buttons where all the values of the use selected radio buttons need to be stored and posted to another page where I can perform some CURD operations of MongoDB.

Comment: @Ravi, I have edited the question with some examples.

Comment: @Puneeth: Add name="submit" in your form button.

Comment: @Ravi, One thing I will make it clear, User can only select one answer with radio button. In such a way user has answered 20 questions, now how to get the values of all these radio buttons which user has selected as answer.

Comment: @Puneeth: Now I get you.

Comment: Check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960036/multiple-radio-button-array-for-php-form

Comment: @RaviHirani, I did understand much there, Should I do the POST with in the same page or in another page? Can you provide the code snippet?

Comment: @RaviHirani, I mean I did not understood much there.

Comment: @Epodax, I have another problem it is allowing me to select only 2 radio buttons. If I select answer for third questions, previous selection will go off.

Answer (score 1):

To make a multiple choice, you have to use input of type checkbox instead of radio. Here is an example :

HTML file :

```
<form action="my_file.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="5">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And in your PHP file :

```
foreach($_POST['check'] as $check) {
        echo $check; 
}
```

In `$_POST['check']` you have all the value that you have select

**Edit multiple question**

First method : use different variable name foreach question :

```
 <form action="test.php" method="post">
    <p>
        Part of main memory where it stores data temporarirly :
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer1[]" value="ROM"> ROM
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer1[]" value="FLOPPY DISK"> FLOPPY DISK
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer1[]" value="RAM"> RAM
        </p>
    </p>
    <p>
        It is a component of operating system that exposes function to user and applications :
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer2[]" value="Shell"> Shell
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer2[]" value="Kernel"> Kernel
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer2[]" value="Shell and Kernel"> Shell and Kernel
        </p>
    </p>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

So in this case you have the answer of the first question in `$_POST['answer1']`, the answer of the second in `$_POST['answer2']`...

Second method : multidimensionnal array

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <p>
        Part of main memory where it stores data temporarirly :
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer[1][]" value="ROM"> ROM
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer[1][]" value="FLOPPY DISK"> FLOPPY DISK
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer[1][]" value="RAM"> RAM
        </p>
    </p>
    <p>
        It is a component of operating system that exposes function to user and applications :
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer[2][]" value="Shell"> Shell
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer[2][]" value="Kernel"> Kernel
            <input type="checkbox" name="answer[2][]" value="Shell and Kernel"> Shell and Kernel
        </p>
    </p>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

In this case, your answer are all in the multidimensionnal array `$_POST['answer']`. But to access at the answer of the first question you have to do `$_POST['answer'][1]`. This is also an array that contains all answers that you have select for the first question.

Comment: I see your suggestion working partially, but I am getting following error if I submit, "The requested URL /cc/post was not found on this server." But I can see the checked values over address bar.

Comment: Have you specify the action value in the form? Look my edit : <form action="your_file.php" method="post">

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I was doing this but have interchanged the actions. But There is a serious a problem in this. It is echoing the previously selected options too. I know I need to flush the form or something but how to do that? Or anything else I must do here.

Comment: May be do i need clean the array that had stored earlier?

Comment: The previous that are selected, you mean it's option of the previous questions? If is that you have to do a variable by question. So for each question the input does not have the same name. Hope I have understood your problem. Look my edit.

Comment: My questions and options are displayed from DB hence I am running the echo in for loop, So I cant use the scenario u present here. Earlier I have used radio button but radio/checked box doesnt matter as of now. Two problems to high light 1) Previous selected options are getting displayed. 2) If only one option is selected for the entire page, nothing is getting printed. Does random selection in my code has any problem?

Answer (score 1):

1) Add `name="submit"` in your form button.

`<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>`

Now you can check

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
 // do stuff
}
```

2) You have completely wrongly used radio button in PHP. **Using Radio button you can select only one value NOT more than one in same group**.

You can use Radio button in PHP by below way:-

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio 1">Radio 1
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio 2">Radio 2
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio 3">Radio 3
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
```

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if(isset($_POST['radio'])){
  echo "You have selected :".$_POST['radio'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
  }
}
```

**If you want to select more than one value then use checkbox.**

```
<form action="checkbox.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="flavours[]" value="strawberry">
    <input type="checkbox" name="flavours[]" value="vanilla">
    <input type="checkbox" name="flavours[]" value="chocolate">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form> 


<?php  // checkbox.php

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
exit;


// submitting the form with a random selection of flavours will give:


array(2) {
  ["flavours"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "strawberry"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "vanilla"
  }
}

// If you leave all checkboxes unselected, $_POST['flavours'] will not be set.
```

Comment: So use checbox in your answer, not radio buttons. No ?

Comment: @ThinkTank: The question is related to Radio button that's  why I have added example of radio button. I have also added an example of checkbox.

Comment: @Ravi, In my code i have for loop which say displays 20 questions with multiple choices in a radio button, does your POST code stores 20 radio button values?

Comment: @Ravi Hirani : the true question was about "multiple answers". In your first post there was no checkbox, only radio. Since you have edited, I'll remove my -1.