# Undefined index php

Tags: php, html, mysql

My issue is that I am making a dating site form with following categories

`firstname,lastname,username,password,email,mysex,yoursex,relationship,date of birth, and country`

I did the whole php code so when submitted would send info to sql server. But there is some error on php half, date of birth(DOB) day,month,year. And `mysex` and `yoursex` values are not submitting. Sql gives undefined index. Here is my code.(The falf that is not submitting)

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" id="register" class="col-xs-12"> 
<input class="register-switch-input" type="radio" name="mysex" value="hombre" id="me-male" > <label class="register-switch-label" for="me-male"> Hombre </label>
<input class="register-switch-input" type="radio" name="mysex" value="mujer" id="me-female"> <label class="register-switch-label" for="me-female"> Mujer </label> <br>  

<input type="radio" name="yoursex" value="hombre" id="your-male" checked> <label for="your-male"> Hombre </label>
<input  type="radio" name="yoursex" value="mujer" id="your-female"> <label for="your-female"> Mujer </label> 
<input type="radio" name="yoursex" value="cualquiera" id="cualquiera">  <label for="cualquiera">Cualquiera </label> <br> 

<label class="form-label">Nacimiento:</label>
   <select name="DOBMonth" >
   <option> - Month - </option>
   <option value="January">January</option>
   <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
    ""

<select name="DOBDay" >
 <option> - Day - </option>
 ""

<select name="DOBYear">
  <option> - Year - </option>
  <option value="2003">2003</option>
```

The "" is because the selects have a million options and are unnessecary.
Here is my php code

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "diego966";
$password = "ddddd966";
$dbname= "signup";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mysex = $_POST["mysex"];
$yoursex = $_POST["yoursex"];
$relationship = $_POST['relationship'];
$DOBday = $_POST['DOBday'];
$DOBmonth = $_POST['DOBmonth'];
$DOByear = $_POST['DOByear'];
$country = $_POST['country'];




$sql="INSERT INTO accounts(firstname, lastname, username, password, email, mysex, yoursex, relationship, DOBday, DOBmonth, DOByear, country)
        VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname','$username', '$password', '$email','$mysex', '$yoursex', '$relationship', 'DOBday', 'DOBmonth ','DOByear', '$country')"; 

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: sanitise your inputs, don't trust user data. ever. Also you probably have a typo `$DOBday = $_POST['DOBday'];` should be `$DOBday = $_POST['DOBDay'];` - notice the capital on D for day. M for month. Y for year in your `POST` Also for radio buttons your error is probably because the returned value for `$yoursex` is an array

Comment: what do you mean by sanitize my inputs? And yeah i discovered that just before i saw this comment haha. But cant fix the sex yet...

Comment: see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/sanitize-database-inputs/ basically with your code someone could hack your database really easily. get all your customer data. you'll get sued.

Comment: @ChelseaStats if by an array your refering to the double quotation marks i fixed that just now but still no progress :/

Comment: Then also look at using bind variables http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: for arrays from radio buttons see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960036/multiple-radio-button-array-for-php-form

Comment: @ChelseaStats ok,i will be sure to read all of those links and apply what i can. But for now i want the data to reach the database. You dont know how i can do that right?

Comment: do a var_dump($_POST); before inserting and make sure it is as you expect, you will probably find something like $_POST['mysex']['0'], you need to check which mysex and which yoursex are being set.

Comment: @ChelseaStats i apreciate your help but i am really new to php and dont know how to do this. I have to add var_dump($_POST); at the end of my php script and run it?

Answer (score 1):

As partly mentioned in the comments:

- DOBMonth is DOBmonth in PHP
- DOBYear is DOByear in PHP
- DOBDay is DOBday in PHP
- your radio-field needs to be defined by `name="yoursex[]"` in HTML and then you check in PHP if `isset($_POST["yoursex"])` and then you can use $_POST["yoursex"][0]

Sanitizing has been mentioned but can not be mentioned enough

Comment: why the 0 array after your sex?