# How to get checked inputs from HMTL5 table

Tags: php, jquery, html, radio-button, html-table

I would like to know if someone has an idea on how to get the checked values of the radio-buttons. There are 5 Columns and several rows, the user can only select one radio-button per column.

I have been trying to get the values but I haven't been able to get it through JQuery, or sending it through post to a PHP file.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover " id='tableIncoming'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Route</th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {section name=lindex loop=$INCOMING_LIST}       
        <tr style="" class="{if $INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name eq 'Tres Rios' || $INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name eq 'Cartago'}info{/if}" id="tr{$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}-{$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time}"> 
            <td>{$smarty.section.lindex.index +1}</td>
            <td style="width:220px;"> {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time} </td>  
            <td><input name="M" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="T" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="W" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="Th" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="F" type="radio"></td>
        </tr> 
        {/section}
        <tr style="" class="" id='trWNUI'> 
            <td>-</td>
            <td  style="width:220px;" name='wnui'>Will not use</td>  
            <td><input name="M" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="T" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="W" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="Th" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="F" type="radio"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Table]
**SOLUTION**
Thanks to @Lennon, I updated my table to provide the values, here is how the code looks now:

```
{section name=lindex loop=$INCOMING_LIST}       
    <tr style="" class="{if $INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name eq 'Tres Rios' || $INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name eq 'Cartago'}info{/if}" id="tr{$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}-{$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time}"> 
        <td>{$smarty.section.lindex.index +1}</td>
        <td style="width:220px;"> {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time} </td>  
        <td><input name="Mi[]" value='I, M, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time}' type="radio"></td>
        <td><input name="Ti[]" value='I, T, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time}' type="radio"></td>
        <td><input name="Wi[]" value='I, W, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time}' type="radio"></td>
        <td><input name="Thi[]" value='I, Th, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time}' type="radio"></td>
        <td><input name="Fi[]" value='I, F, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time}' type="radio"></td>
    </tr> 
{/section}
```

Comment: Give your inputs values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use brackets on the name of your radio buttons.
So that when you submit them, PHP will recognize it as an array.

Example here: [Multiple radio button array for php form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960036/multiple-radio-button-array-for-php-form)

This:

```
<tr style="" class="{if $INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name eq 'Tres Rios' || $INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name eq 'Cartago'}info{/if}" id="tr{$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}-{$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time}"> 
            <td>{$smarty.section.lindex.index +1}</td>
            <td style="width:220px;"> {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time} </td>  
            <td><input name="M" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="T" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="W" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="Th" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="F" type="radio"></td>
        </tr>
```

Need to be this:

```
<tr style="" class="{if $INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name eq 'Tres Rios' || $INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name eq 'Cartago'}info{/if}" id="tr{$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}-{$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time}"> 
            <td>{$smarty.section.lindex.index +1}</td>
            <td style="width:220px;"> {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time} </td>  
            <td><input name="M[]" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="T[]" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="W[]" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="Th[]" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="F[]" type="radio"></td>
        </tr>
```

And you access through $_POST['m']['ID_OF_CHECKED_ITEM']

Comment: Why does he need an array? He has a different name for each column, so they'll be in `$_POST['M']`, `$_POST['T']` and so on.

Comment: My question to your answer, is, how would I know if the radio-button is checked when getting it on PHP. Because, I only need the 'route and day' so I can make the reservation.

Please excuse my ignorance, I have been working on getting this done for over a week, with unsuccessful results and I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Only selected values are submitted, if its not on the array, it has not been checked.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is give the radio buttons of the same row the same "name"

for e.g:

```
<tr style="" class="{if $INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name eq 'Tres Rios' || $INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name eq 'Cartago'}info{/if}" id="tr{$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}-{$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time}"> 
            <td>{$smarty.section.lindex.index +1}</td>
            <td style="width:220px;"> {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time} </td>  
            <td><input name="M" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="T" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="W" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="Th" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="F" type="radio"></td>
        </tr>
```

**Should change to:**

```
<tr style="" class="{if $INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name eq 'Tres Rios' || $INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name eq 'Cartago'}info{/if}" id="tr{$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}-{$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time}"> 
            <td>{$smarty.section.lindex.index +1}</td>
            <td style="width:220px;"> {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].name}, {$INCOMING_LIST[lindex].time} </td>  
            <td><input name="row1" value="M" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="row1" value="T" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="row1" value="W" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="row1" value="Th" type="radio"></td>
            <td><input name="row1" value="F" type="radio"></td>
        </tr>
```

and you can access the value as `$('row1').val()` in jquery or in php as `$_POST['row1']`