# How do I send bound variables to another page to then update the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a database dependant on an whether the radio button has been clicked or not for a number of different rows which have all been generated from the database. I've managed to select all of the data and store them into radio buttons fine. However, I'm having trouble passing the variables onto the next page to run the update function. I haven't used the update function before and I'm struggling to find others who have had the same issue.

Below is the code for the radio buttons and each variable value:

```
$name1 = "week1" . $ind;
            $name2 = "week2" . $ind;
            $name3 = "week3" . $ind;
            $name4 = "week4" . $ind;
            $name5 = "week5" . $ind;
            $name6 = "week6" . $ind;
            $name7 = "week7" . $ind;
            $name8 = "week8" . $ind;
            $name9 = "week9" . $ind;
            $name10 = "week10" . $ind;
            $SID2="SID" . $ind;
            $ClassID2 = "ClassID" . $ind;
            $StudentName2 = "StudentName" . $ind;

            print ("<form action='Table/Update2.php' method='post'><tr>");

            //print a cell
            print ("<td> <input type ='hidden' name ='". $SID2."' value ='".$SID."'> $SID </td>");
            print ("<td> <input type ='hidden' name ='" . $ClassID2 . "' value ='" . $ClassID . "'> $ClassID </td>");
            print ("<td> <input type ='hidden' name ='" . $StudentName2 . "'value='".$StudentName."'> $StudentName </td>");
    // print the radio buttons
            print ("<td> $week_1 <input type='radio' value='1' name=" . $name1 ." " . (($week_1 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' value='0' name=" . $name1 ." " . (($week_1 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_2 <input type='radio' name=" . $name2 ." " . (($week_2 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name2 ." " . (($week_2 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_3 <input type='radio' name=" . $name3 ." " . (($week_3 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name3 ." " . (($week_3 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_4 <input type='radio' name=" . $name4 ." " . (($week_4 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name4 ." " . (($week_4 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_5 <input type='radio' name=" . $name5 ." " . (($week_5 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name5 ." " . (($week_5 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_6 <input type='radio' name=" . $name6 ." " . (($week_6 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name6 ." " . (($week_6 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_7 <input type='radio' name=" . $name7 ." " . (($week_7 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name7 ." " . (($week_7 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_8 <input type='radio' name=" . $name8 ." " . (($week_8 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name8 ." " . (($week_8 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_9 <input type='radio' name=" . $name9 ." " . (($week_9 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name9 ." " . (($week_9 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");
            print ("<td> $week_10 <input type='radio' name=" . $name10 ." " . (($week_10 == '1')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "><input type='radio' name=" . $name10 ." " . (($week_10 == '0')? 'checked=\"checked\"' :"") .  "></td> ");

            //close row
            print ("</tr>");
            $ind++;
```

And below is the next page receiving the data, which I believe is the main issue:

```
$SID =( isset ($_POST['".SID2 ."']));
$ClassID = (isset ($_POST['" . $ClassID2 . "']));
$StudentName = (isset ($_POST[ '" . $StudentName2 . "']));

$week1 = ( isset ($_POST ['". $name1 . "']) ? '1':'0' );
$week2 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name2 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week3 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name3 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week4 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name4 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week5 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name5 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week6 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name6 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week7 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name7 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week8 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name8 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week9 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name9 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
$week10 = ( isset ($_POST [ '". $name10 . "']) ? '1' : '0');
```

Then below is the SQL statement, which keeps cropping up with the HY093 error:

```
$sqlQuery = "Update weekbyweek SET (:SID =?, :ClassID=?, :StudentName=?, :Week_1=?, :Week_2=?, :Week_3=?, :Week_4=?, :Week_5=?, :Week_6=?, :Week_7=?, :Week_8=?, :Week_9=?, :Week_10=?)";
$statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
$statement->execute([':SID'=> $SID, ':ClassID'=> $ClassID, ':StudentName' => $StudentName, ':Week_1' => $week1, ':Week_2' => $week2, ':Week_3' => $week3, ':Week_4' => $week4,':Week_5' => $week5, ':Week_6' => $week6,':Week_7' => $week7, ':Week_8' => $week8,':Week_9' => $week9, ':Week_10' => $week10]);
```

I'm presuming I haven't bound the values properly on this next page.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have basically 2 problems
 Fist

> SET (:SID =?

both sides :SID and ? are placeholders and when you decided to used named variables (:SID) you can only use :SID but this is only valif on the right side

Like

> SID = :SID

The left side is the columnname and the right side is the placeholder ´, to which you bind the $SID

The second problem are the parenthesis, mysql don't like them jn the way you use it,in your case get rid of them

So you get the next code, of course i don't know your database, so i can't guarantee that this will work.

```
$sqlQuery = "Update weekbyweek SET SID = :SID, ClassID = :ClassID, StudentName=:StudentName, Week_1= :Week_1, Week_2=:Week_2, Week_3=:Week_3, Week_4=:Week_4, Week_5= :Week_5, Week_6= :Week_6, Week_7= :Week_7, Week_8= :Week_8, Week_9= :Week_0, Week_10=:Week_10";
$statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
$statement->execute([':SID'=> $SID, ':ClassID'=> $ClassID, ':StudentName' => $StudentName, ':Week_1' => $week1, ':Week_2' => $week2, ':Week_3' => $week3, ':Week_4' => $week4,':Week_5' => $week5, ':Week_6' => $week6,':Week_7' => $week7, ':Week_8' => $week8,':Week_9' => $week9, ':Week_10' => $week10]);
```

But when you have a error Hhadnling  the problem should be eeasily soved,

When i saw your code i thought, why didn't heuse arrays see [Multiple radio button array for php form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960036/multiple-radio-button-array-for-php-form)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much that fixed my issue of  being able to successfully update. However, it did overwrite every number with 0, which I'm presuming leads me onto the next bit you mentioned with the arrays. Would I just save put all variables in lets say $UpdateAll in one array & then do a foreach ($UpdateAll -> $Query)?

Comment: I don;t suppose you'd be able to help me to update the database with the bound values? I've put ``` $statement->bindColumn(':SID', $SID);
$statement->bindColumn(':ClassID', $ClassID); ```  for each variable & then kept the rest the same. But it's still overwriting the values?

Comment: at the moment i can't follow you, stay with your old improved code, because now you are talkinh about something that i don-'t know. Basically you get an id and try to changes the data in your data abse, so it overwrites the data, as your program makes.

Comment: That's not a problem. Thank you very much for your help.