# How can i get all of the values of the radio button even if there is no selected?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to store question choices on my database.

the layout is like this.

```html
<div id="question-choices" class="component-answer-choices-table-item-wrapper">
                                <div class="component-answer-choices-table-item">
                                    <input type="text" name="question_answer_choices[0]" value="" placeholder="Click to enter a choice">
                                    <input type="radio" name="answer_level" value="0">
                                </div>
                                <div class="component-answer-choices-table-item">
                                    <input type="text" name="question_answer_choices[1]" value="" placeholder="Click to enter a choice">
                                    <input type="radio" name="answer_level" value="1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="component-answer-choices-table-item">
                                    <input type="text" name="question_answer_choices[2]" value="" placeholder="Click to enter a choice">
                                    <input type="radio" name="answer_level" value="2">
                                </div>
                                <div class="component-answer-choices-table-item">
                                    <input type="text" name="question_answer_choices[3]" value="" placeholder="Click to enter a choice">
                                    <input type="radio" name="answer_level" value="3">
                                </div>
                                <div class="component-answer-choices-table-item">
                                    <input type="text" name="question_answer_choices[4]" value="" placeholder="Click to enter a choice">
                                    <input type="radio" name="answer_level" value="4">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

So I will enter choices from the fields, then with the radio button, I will choose there if what is the right answer.

so if I enter

4 choices

```
A. Choices 1 - radio button not selected
B. Choices 2 - radio button not selected
C. Choices 3 - radio button not selected
D. Choices 4 - radio button selected
```

if the radio button is selected, then the value is 1 and the rest is 0.

How can I store this on my database? can anyone help me on how can I do this?

if I insert this on my database it should look like this.

```
id |    choices   | correct_answer
1     choices 1          0
2     choices 2          0
3     choices 3          0
4     choices 4          1
```

I know how to get the values of choices, but I don't know how can I know what is the selected correct answer and how can I insert it.

here is my code, I think I am already close to my problem but I still don't know on how to solve it :(

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

      $choices = $request->get('question_answer_choices');
      $answer_level = $request->get('answer_level');

       for ($i=0; $i < count($choices) ; $i++) {

        if ($i == $answer_level) {
          $answer_level = 1;
        }

        if (!empty($choices[$i])) {
          $question_choices[] = [
              'question_id' =>  $question_id,
              'choice' => $choices[$i],
              'choice_level' =>$answer_level,
              'created_by' => Auth::user()->id
          ];
        }
      }

    }
```

I can already get which radio button is correct answer in the choices, but I don't know how can I insert the rest of the choices with a value of 0 :(.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960036/multiple-radio-button-array-for-php-form

Comment: i already look at it sir, it seems that it doesn't match for the problem that i have :(

Comment: You should not be _overwriting_ the $answer_level variable there, you should use a different variable - that you set to 0 or 1, depending on whether the $answer_level is equal to $i, or not. `if ($i == $answer_level) { $choice_level = 1; } else  { $choice_level = 0; }` And then you use that variable for the `choice_level` in your insert statement.

Comment: @CBroe yes sir, i just realized it too, thats why i am getting wrong result. thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

You save a table

`user_choice`

```
user_id    question_id     choice_number
```

And you have a table

`question`

```
question_id   question_content   correct_answer_number
```

`answers`

```
question_id    answer     order
```

With following query you can see all the question that user 10 made and it checks all the answers if correct or not

```
SELECT 
    uc.user_id
    , q.question_content   
    , IF (q.correct_answer_number = uc.choice_number,"correct","incorrect")  
From 
   user_choice uc INNER JOIN question q ON uc.question_id = q.question_id 
Where user_id = 10
```

For multiple choice, you would add another table, with the corect answers for every quesion and the same goes for the answers from the user.

The answers table is simple a question_id , a answer text and the order defines in which order it gets displayed and which value the answer gets.

you could move the correct answers value to this table, but as you would have to join the answer table every time.

Comment: I think this is for the user side sir, I have no problem with the user side sir, I am on admin side where I am adding question and choices for the user to see it. for the problem that i have is, I am adding choices and choosing which is the correct answer from that choices.

Comment: that is what you save in the able questions, as your code indicates that the suer has only one choice i also have only 1 choice per question, this you would make in the admin side. When the user gest a question from the question list, you save its answer in the user_choice table

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help someone who is a beginner like me.

so for me to insert the unselected radio button.

```
     public function store(Request $request)
     {

       //Choices
       $question_id = $questions->id;
       $choices = $request->get('question_answer_choices');
       $answer_level = $request->get('answer_level');

       for ($i=0; $i < count($choices) ; $i++) {

           if ($i == $answer_level) {

             if (!empty($choices[$i])) {
                 $question_choices[] = [
                     'question_id' =>  $question_id,
                     'choice' => $choices[$i],
                     'choice_level' =>1,
                     'created_by' => Auth::user()->id
                 ];
             }

           }else{

             if (!empty($choices[$i])) {
                 $question_choices[] = [
                     'question_id' =>  $question_id,
                     'choice' => $choices[$i],
                     'choice_level' =>0,
                     'created_by' => Auth::user()->id
                 ];
             }
          }
      }

      Question_choice::insert($question_choices);
     // End Choices

       return response()->json([
           'success'=>"Success"
       ]);
     }
```

I just made sure that the value of my radio button will match the index count of my choices input.